# How to disable keyboard lights and underglow lights in Asus ROG Strix, G531GT with Linux Mint OS?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard, power-management, keyboard-backlight

I am using a new laptop, Asus ROG Strix, G531GT-AL041T, G Core i7 9th Gen, and running Linux Mint 19.2 Tina on it. I am unable to find any option that could disable the keyboard lights and in particular the underglow lights which make the laptop look unaesthetic in day light. Moreover, I do not wish to waste the battery power in something that is totally unnecessary. Is there a way to fix this issue?